# Python 3 Better way to schedule a function to run when a certain time is reached?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am trying to find the best way to schedule a function to execute in my python program. Currently I have the following code; which works but I am curious if there is a better way.

```
from datetime import datetime

start_time =  datetime(2019, 7, 26, 14, 48, 10, 28061)

def do_something():
    return 2+2

while True:
    if (datetime.now() > start_time):
        do_something()
        break
```

Is this a *BAD way* to do this? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

Comment: you should use cron jobs or scheduler libraries in python such as [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html)

Comment: I agreed with @amanb. It is more maintainable to use cron jobs or scheduler libraries since those will also take care of terminate/stop/start/restart/alert of  the execution should unexpected result were to happen. With the proposed approach, you might not even know that the code stop running until something bad happens.

Comment: Assuming you're on linux, "jobber" is another gem for scheduling jobs.